# pthread conditions and process termination

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, ipc

I have a process-shared pthread condition (with associated mutex).  What would happen if a process waiting on this condition (using pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait()) gets terminated?  Can this condition still be used by other processes?

In my scenario process #1 waits on the condition and gets terminated.   Process #2 at some point sees that it's the only one now using the condition and calls pthread_cond_destroy().

What i m seeing is that pthread_cond_destroy() simply hangs.  Has anyone encountered the same problem?

From the man page of pthread_cond_destroy() it says that destroying the condition on which some thread is still waiting results in undefined behavior.  In my case nobody is waiting anymore when process #2 calls pthread_cond_destroy() because the waiting process #1 was terminated, but apparently the condition itself still thinks there is a waiting thread.

Is there any way around this problem?

Edit:

Per request, i post the sample programs (i reversed p1 & p2 here):

p1.cpp:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyCond {
    pthread_mutex_t m;
    pthread_cond_t c;
};

int main()
{
    pthread_mutexattr_t ma;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&ma);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&ma, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

pthread_condattr_t ca;
pthread_condattr_init(&ca);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&ca, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

int fd = shm_open("/test_cond_p", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
ftruncate(fd, sizeof(MyCond));

MyCond *c = (MyCond *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MyCond),
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd, 0);
//close (fd);

pthread_mutex_init(&c->m, &ma);
pthread_cond_init(&c->c, &ca);
printf("Inited MyCond, %x\n", c);

puts("Press Enter to continue");
fgetc(stdin);

    int r = pthread_cond_signal(&c->c);
    printf("After pthread_cond_signal, r=%d\n", r);

puts("Before pthread_cond_destroy");
r = pthread_cond_destroy(&c->c);
printf("After pthread_cond_destroy, r=%d\n", r);
r = pthread_mutex_destroy(&c->m);
printf("After pthread_mutex_destroy, r=%d\n", r);

munmap(c, sizeof(MyCond));
shm_unlink("/test_cond_p");

return 0;
}
```

p2.cpp:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

struct MyCond {
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_cond_t c;
};

int main()
{
int fd = shm_open("/test_cond_p", O_RDWR, 0666);

MyCond *c = (MyCond *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(MyCond),
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED,fd, 0);
//close (fd);

pthread_mutex_lock(&c->m);
puts("Before pthread_cond_wait");
int r = pthread_cond_wait(&c->c, &c->m);
printf("After pthread_cond_wait, r=%d\n", r);

munmap(c, sizeof(MyCond));
return 0;
}
```

Run p1 first, then run p2, after it says "before pthread_cond_wait", Ctrl-C it.  Then press Enter in p1's shell.

At first, i was not able to reproduce the hang, but i had both pthread_cond_destroy() and pthread_mutex_destroy() to return EBUSY.

But now the hang reproduces if we call pthread_cond_signal() before pthread_cond_destroy() (see the code above).

Comment: Does 'was terminated' mean pthread_cancel was called? In that case you should enable cleanup handlers.  Here is  POSIX example of this for a user-defined rwlock object, using a mutex.  See Example section:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/pthread_cleanup_pop.html

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: To Jim: no i mean when the whole process terminates via a signal, and let's assume there is no way to intercept that signal to do any cleanup.

Comment: To Pilcrow:  there is a lot of other unrelated things going on in the code so the whole code would be hard to post here, but to clarify the scenario:  process #2 creates shared memory segment to store the condition and it's associated mutex and calls pthread_cond_init() and pthread_mutex_init() on them (with pthread_process_shared attribute enabled).  Then it keeps running doing other stuff.  Process #1 maps into the said shared memory segment getting pointer to the condition and mutex variables.  Then it aquires the mutex and calls pthread_cond_wait() waiting on the condition.

Comment: Then i terminate process #1 (say using Ctrl-C from the shell).  At some point later process #2 decides to destroy the condition and calls pthread_cond_destroy().  This hangs.

Comment: @YevgeniyP, show us a [short, self contained, correct (and compilable) example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.  Write two processes that include the relevant logic from your problematic code, and nothing more.

Comment: This is to be expected. Pthreads primitives are not kernel objects, they are just regiins of memory and they cannot keep track of processes which use them. The workaround is simply not to destroy them. The destruction is essentially a no-oo anyway, there should be no resource leak or other ill effects. You can also try to broadcast on the condvar before freeing it (not sure it will help though).

Comment: I tried pthread_cond_broadcast, it also causes it to hang just like pthread_cond_signal.  This seems to be a big design flaw then.  What's the point of supporting PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED option if they cannot handle process termination.   For mutexes though, there is a robust option which allows to detect when process holding the mutex dies.  They should have something similar for conditions then.

Comment: Do you suggest to just never call pthread_cond_destroy and pthread_mutex_destroy?  I wouldn't be leaking memory or other resources?

Comment: @YevgeniyP, file a bug report!  I can reproduce this behavior with shared memory/PSHARED primitives (I have a child process die by `alarm()` during the condition wait), but not with unshared primitives between two threads of the same process (one of which is `pthread_cancel`d during the wait).  I don't see that you've implicated any undefined behavior, so this strikes me as a bug.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do not destroy, just free the memory and about them. They should not consume any resources (in the glibc implementation anyway). You can always check in glibc source code.

Comment: @pilcrow This is not a bug that can be fixed so it's a bit pointless to file a report.

Comment: To n.m.: thanks for the advice, i m kinda wary of this though.  This might be implementation dependent, so might not be portable.  Also, if condition internally keeps a list of threads waiting for it and does not cleanup ones from dead processes, then if we repeat the same scenario many times, won't we have a growing memory problem?

Comment: Tp pilcrow: i agree this is a bug or a design flaw.  Fixing it though would probably require a change in the kernel, not just glibc.  Basically the kernel would have to have some reference to (a list of) pthread_conds in user space to do appropriate cleanup when the process is killed.  I don't know if they will want to do this change.

Comment: A shared-memory-able resource (like conditional variable or mutex) cannot contain any library-managed pointers or other means to access library-allocated memory. One cannot manage memory in many address spaces at the same time. So no, there's no possibility to leak memory. There's also no possibility to leak kernel resources because no self-respecting kernel would ever allow that, even if a process dies without freeing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the p2 process is waiting on the conditional variable eternally since the p1 process has no chance to send a notification being terminated by ctrl-c. As you and other people have already mentioned pthread conditional variable does not "know" about its original process termination.

If you cannot use another inter process communication features and still insist on shared mutex and conditional variable, I would think about trapping the signal.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, i guess i will need to use different IPC communication method.  Since i m writing a library, it might not be good idea to trap a signal, to avoid interfering with application's signal handling.

Answer (score 4):

The source code of [pthread_cond_destroy](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/pthread_cond_destroy.c#L52) says the following:

> Thus, we can assume that all waiters that are still accessing the condvar have been woken.  We wait until they have confirmed to have woken up by decrementing __wrefs.

So we can simply reset __wrefs to zero before pthread_cond_destroy:

```
c->c.__data.__wrefs = 0;
r = pthread_cond_destroy(&c->c);
```

I ran you sample with this change and P1 completes with no hang.

Note that before [this commit](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/commit/ed19993b5b0d05d62cc883571519a67dae481a14#diff-e958a6d5d13369ff5e32c975448cab17) __wrefs was called __nwaiters.

Answer (score 1):

One more option might be the explicitly call [pthread_ond_broadcast()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html) before calling pthread_cond_destroy().

Like this:

```
r = pthread_cond_broadcast(&c->c);
puts("Before pthread_cond_destroy");
r = pthread_cond_destroy(&c->c);
printf("After pthread_cond_destroy, r=%d\n", r);
r = pthread_mutex_destroy(&c->m);
printf("After pthread_mutex_destroy, r=%d\n", r);
```