# destroying an orphaned process-shared condition variable

Tags: pthreads, posix, shared-memory

Is the behavior of `pthread_cond_destroy` on an orphaned, process-shared condition variable specified, unspecified, implementation-defined, or undefined?  Also, is the behavior I'm seeing on Linux (spelled out below) a bug?

By an "orphaned" cv here I mean one that was in a `pthread_cond_wait` call at the time of its waiter's death.

Adapting a scenario from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20439404/132382), I find that if I do this on Linux:

```
Time  Process A                Process B             Comments
----  ---------                ---------             --------
 1    mmap MAP_ANONYMOUS                             // or shm_open()
 2    init pshared cv
 3    init pshared mutex
 4    fork ------------------> lock(mutex)           // can also re-shm_open()
 5    wait...                  alarm(a_timeout)
 6    wait...                  cond_wait(cv, mutex)
 7    wait <------------------ <<ALRM>>
 8    cond_signal(cv)                                // (without this, EBUSY for #9)
 9    cond_destroy(cv)                               // blocks on linux
```

On Linux, the destroy() (#9) blocks forever.  If I omit the signal (#8) to the orphaned cv, then the Linux destroy() returns EBUSY.  On OS X, by contrast, the destroy() always returns EBUSY, regardless of signaling or not.

For what it's worth, I do *not* see this behavior on Linux with process-shared mutexes and cvs in a single multi-threaded process (with the waiting thread cancel()d).

Again, what's spec and what's bug?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec for pthread_cond_destroy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html)

> "It shall be safe to destroy an initialized condition variable upon
>   which no threads are currently blocked"

As this is exactly the case, i.e. there are no other threads whatsoever that reference or are blocked on the condition variable, the destroy shall by successful.

IMHO, we have bugs in both operating system in that the condition variable object is left in an inconsistent state.