# strange behavior of pthread_cond_destroy() hanging

Tags: pthreads, freeze

I know that `pthread_cancel()` is tricky. I ask this question to understand a bug in a software where `pthread_cancel()` is used.

I simplified the problem to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static pthread_mutex_t notify_mutex;
static pthread_cond_t notify;

static void *_watcher_thread(void *arg)
{
    (void) pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    (void) pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    printf("watcher:   thread started\n");

    while (1) {
            if (pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL) != 0) {
                    perror("failed to disable watcher thread cancel: ");
            }
            pthread_mutex_lock(&notify_mutex);
            pthread_cond_wait(&notify, &notify_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&notify_mutex);
            (void) pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    }
    return NULL;
}

static void *_timer_thread(void *args)
{
    (void) pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    (void) pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    printf("timer:   thread started\n");

    while (1) {
            if (pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL) != 0) {
                    perror("failed to disable timer thread cancel: ");
            }
            pthread_mutex_lock(&notify_mutex); /* XXX: not a cancellation point */
            pthread_cond_signal(&notify);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&notify_mutex);
            (void) pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t watcher_tid, timer_tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    long i = 0;

    while (1) {
            pthread_cond_init(&notify, NULL);
            pthread_mutex_init(&notify_mutex, NULL);
            pthread_attr_init(&attr);

            if (pthread_create(&watcher_tid, &attr,
                               &_watcher_thread, NULL)) {
                    perror("failed to create watcher thread: ");
            }
            if (pthread_create(&timer_tid, &attr,
                               &_timer_thread, NULL)) {
                    perror("failed to create timer thread: ");
            }

            sleep(1);

            printf("main:   to cancel watcher thread\n");
            pthread_cancel(watcher_tid);
            pthread_join(watcher_tid, NULL);
            printf("main:   watcher thread canceled\n");

            printf("main:   to cancel timer thread\n");
            pthread_cancel(timer_tid);
            pthread_join(timer_tid, NULL);
            printf("main:   timer thread canceled\n");

            pthread_cond_destroy(&notify);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&notify_mutex);
            pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
            i ++;
            printf("iteration: %ld\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically there are three threads: watcher, timer, and main. The timer thread wakes up the watcher thread periodically to do some work. And finally the main thread terminates the other threads and exits. I write some loops in the above test program to reproduce the problem.

Compile and run the program in Linux (debian testing, 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP, glibc-2.24), it will hang after some iterations:

```
...
main:   to cancel timer thread
main:   timer thread canceled
iteration: 4
timer:   thread started
watcher:   thread started
main:   to cancel watcher thread
main:   watcher thread canceled
main:   to cancel timer thread
main:   timer thread canceled
iteration: 5
timer:   thread started
watcher:   thread started
main:   to cancel watcher thread
main:   watcher thread canceled
main:   to cancel timer thread
main:   timer thread canceled
```

gdb shows the stack trace of the hanging program:

```
(gdb) attach 29247
Attaching to process 29247
Reading symbols from /home/hjcao/temp/test/pthread/hang1...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
0x00007f796070bf2b in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f796070bf2b in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f7960708eb5 in pthread_cond_destroy@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x0000561b1f194f01 in main () at hang1.c:78
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7f7960b12700 (LWP 29247) "hang1" 0x00007f796070bf2b in __lll_lock_wait_private () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
(gdb)
```

=======================================================

My Question is:  I do not understand why the main thread will hang in `pthread_cond_destroy()`.

Indeed the original program(with name hang0) does not has the `pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL)` and `pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL)` calls in the while loops in the watcher/timer threads. It will hang in the main thread, which is understandable: asynchronously canceling the watcher/timer thread may result in the thread being canceled during executing in `pthread_cond_wait()`/`pthread_cond_notify()` and left the condition variable `notify` messed up internally.  I added the `pthread_setcancelstate()` calls to prevent the watcher/timer thread from being canceled when manipulating the condition variable. But the new program (with name hang1) still hangs.

Could somebody please help me to explain this?

Comment: How exactly do you compile?

Comment: Asynchronous cancelling is mostly a bad idea. You want to apply *complete* error checking to all POSIX-Threads-API calls and will learn more.

Comment: *If* cancelling a thread, deferred cancelling is the preferred way.

Comment: For your example to work with deferred cancellation the thread's `while`-loops need to introduce a cancellation point. A simple `sleep(0)` would do.

Answer (score 1):

I think this thread can be of help :
  [pthread conditions and process termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20439404/pthread-conditions-and-process-termination)
  (the answer by Gusev Petr helped me fix my issue)

I had the same issue of condition variable hanging at the `pthread_cond_destroy()` function.

Its mostly because the condition variable doesn't have logic to find out whether the thread on which it has been waiting is still running or dead (normally due to `pthread_cancel()`). So one possible solution is to force change the value in the variable to 0 as explained in the above link.